# Reading NSPoint from text file

Tags: iphone, ios

I save two CGPoints(in an array) into a text file in the Documents directory. When I read the file, this is what I get:

```
NSPoint: {66.5, 87}, NSPoint: {198.5, 314.5}
```

How do I get an output like this:

```
66.5 87
198.5 314.5
```

Here's my code:

```
//save the coordinates of two points into a text file in the Documents directory
- (void)savePoints
{
    //get Document directory's path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"POINTS.txt"];

    //create an points array
    NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&fromPoint objCType:@encode(CGPoint)]]; //insert object at the end of the array
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&toPoint objCType:@encode(CGPoint)]];

    //write points array to file
    BOOL result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:points toFile:fullPath];
    NSLog(@"Archival result: %d", result);
}

//read the file
-(void)getPoints
{
    //get Document directory's path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"POINTS.txt"];

    //read points array from file
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
    NSString *str = [points componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Comment: Can u explain ur question little bit.. Do u need to convert the string to CGPoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a line of code that takes your array of two points and then converts it to a string:

```
NSString *str = [points componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

This gives you your:

```
NSPoint: {66.5, 87},NSPoint: {198.5, 314.5}
```

You happen to be doing this in the `getPoints` method, but you would have gotten the same result if you had done this in the `savePoints` method, too. Your problem has nothing to do with the saving to the file or retrieving from the file. It's just a matter of how you want to extract the `CGPoint` values from your `points` array.

So, if you wanted to get your two points back out (which I presume is the real intent), you would do something like:

```
CGPoint fromPoint = [[points objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
CGPoint toPoint = [[points objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue];
```

Or you could, using recent versions of the compiler, do:

```
CGPoint fromPoint = [points[0] CGPointValue];
CGPoint toPoint = [points[1] CGPointValue];
```

Or you could do something like:

```
for (NSValue *value in points)
{
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"point = %.1f, %.1f", point.x, point.y);
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with your two points.

Comment: This can be done easy way using CGPointFromString and NSStringFromCGPoint. Just to share information.

Comment: @JanakNirmal Yes, I know these functions. But this (like most of the other answers) ignores the subtle point that while the question looked like it was about formatting a string value, one can infer that the real question was extracting `CGPoint` values from an array and the OP got a little mixed up in the process of writing to and reading from the file. That's why I used the more cumbersome `point.x` and `point.y` syntax in the `NSLog`, to make it very explicit how to retrieve values. When I'm logging `CGPoint` values, I always use `NSStringFromCGPoint`, but it only clouds to issue here.

Comment: Totally agree with that +1 :D

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
     NSString *strCG=@"{66.5, 87}";
     CGPoint myPoint = CGPointFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strCG]);//StrCG is your Strin
     ScrollObj.contentOffset=myPoint;
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay you got the answer but still for easy process posting this answer, try to use [`NSStringFromCGPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) and [`CGPointFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

```
//save the coordinates of two points into a text file in the Documents directory
- (void)savePoints
{
    //get Document directory's path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"POINTS.txt"];

    CGPoint fromPoint = CGPointMake(66.5, 87);
    CGPoint toPoint = CGPointMake(198.5, 314.5);

    //create an points array
    NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [points addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(fromPoint)]; //Create string from CGPoint
    [points addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(toPoint)]; //Create string from CGPoint

    //write points array to file
    BOOL result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:points toFile:fullPath];
    NSLog(@"Archival result: %d", result);
}

//read the file
-(void)getPoints
{
    //get Document directory's path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"POINTS.txt"];

    //read points array from file
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
    for (NSString *point in points) {
        CGPoint tmpPoint  = CGPointFromString(point); //Create CGPoint from NSString
        NSLog(@"%f %f",tmpPoint.x,tmpPoint.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this may be it'l helps you,

```
NSString * val = @"NSPoint: {66.5, 87}, NSPoint: {198.5, 314.5}";
NSString * strippedNumber = [val stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^.,0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [val length])];
    NSLog(@"%@", strippedNumber);
```

Comment: the two points are from touch event, so they keep changing. I need to strip it while reading it.

Comment: ok no problem you can pass the dynamic string after getting the each and every point.

Comment: i tried using the dynamic string but even the spaces were stripped off

Comment: you can change the value [^.,0-9 ] in this provide the characters whatever you want now it'l not trim the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Xcode` documentation window, search on "`NSValue` `UIKit` Additions Reference" (or google it).

You can directly `encode` a `CGPoint` `(+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point)` and `decode` it with `(- (CGPoint)CGPointValue`).